# changing the color of spinner items

Tags: android, spinner

I tried adding the properties `textcolor` in `styles.xml` file.

Is there any other way to change the color of spinner items?

Answer (score 0):

This file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, Android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(Android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerSubject.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or using

```
spinner.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize spinner text color using this method:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(20);
            ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(custom_typeface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did to my custom spinner:

```
 List<String> tonnage =  new ArrayList<String>();
    tonnage.add("Not Sure");
    tonnage.add("10 Ton");
    tonnage.add("20 Ton");
    tonnage.add("27 Ton");
    tonnage.add("35 Ton");
    tonnage.add("40 Ton");
    tonnage.add("50 Ton");
    tonnage.add("75 Ton");
    tonnage.add("80 Ton");
    tonnage.add("100 Ton");
    tonnage.add("125 Ton");
    tonnage.add("150 Ton");
    tonnage.add("175 Ton");
    tonnage.add("200 Ton");
    tonnage.add("Larger than 200 Ton");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,R.layout.spinner_layout, tonnage);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sItems2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tonrequiredtfholder);
        sItems2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is my spinner_layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/md_green_900"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```